# Estimate on Size of Convex Hull

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^3$, and denote by $Conv(X)$ the *convex hull* of $X$, i.e, the smallest convex subset of $\mathbb R^3$ containing $X$. As $X \subset Conv(X)$ by definiton, the diameter-inequality $diam(X) \leq diam(Conv(X))$ certainly holds, and I wonder if a partial converse is also true:

*There exists an integer $n \in \mathbb N$ and a constant $c > 0$, such that the following holds: If  $\Gamma \subset \mathbb R^3$ is a (smooth) simple closed curve, we have the inequality \begin{equation} diam(Conv(\Gamma)) \leq c*diam(\Gamma)^n \end{equation}*

It can be shown that any (smooth) simple closed curve $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb R^3$ bounds a disc $D$ with $Area(D) \leq (4\pi)^{-1}*length(\Gamma)^2$. However, things get a bit more complicated when passing to the diameter - it is possible to construct a sequence $(D_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ of discs bounded by $\Gamma$ whose diameter grows arbitrarily large as $k \to \infty$, but have uniformly bounded Area. Moreover, the inequality $diam(\Gamma) \leq lenght(\Gamma)$ can easily shown to be true, but it is not possible to find simliar inverse inequality (as can be seen by considering curves inside a small ball that are of large variation). Thus, it seems highly unlikely that the Area-length inequality can be used to relate the diameter of a disc with the diameter of a corresponding boundary curve.

However, when considering a *least area disc* $D$, bounded by $\Gamma$, we have a particularly well-behaved disc, such that $D \subset Conv(\Gamma)$. Therefore, the inequality in question could be used to establish an analogous relation between the diameter of such a disc with its boundary curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the convex hull does not increase the diameter:

$$\textrm{diam}\ ( Conv(X)) = \textrm{diam} (X)$$

This follows from the fact that 
$$d( P, \lambda Q_1 + (1-\lambda) Q_2) \le \lambda d (P, Q_1) + (1-\lambda) d (P, Q_2)$$
as the distance is given by a norm.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the equality also extends to oriented riemannian manifolds. The problem there is, of course, that the metric is not induced by a Norm. I guess that one needs some assumptions on sectional curvature...

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Minor nitpick: the existence of the nowhere-vanishing volume form associated to the Riemannian metric implies that a Riemannian manifold is always oriented.